# Background image not working properly in getView method

Tags: android, listview, android-layout, background, android-linearlayout

Following shows the code and screenshot for displaying data in `listview` containing 4 `textview`  (*out of which only 3 will be displayed*) and 1 `imageView`.

I tried the following code in `getView()` method of `Adapter` class to give different background image to alternate rows i.e. row no. 0,2,4,etc.

When I try to implement this, I get the output as shown in screen-shot i.e. whenever any `textView` data is more so that it wraps to 2nd line, then text is not getting displayed appropriately.

Also **even though `xml` contains `gravity="top"`, still some space is getting left out at top in each row.**

And, **refer to below `xml` in which `alignTop` and `alignBottom` parameters are used, still 2nd row is not getting background color appropriately as it's size is equivalent to 2 lines.**

NOTE : *Even if I use COLOR instead of IMAGE for background, the result is same. So I guess, issue is not related with image dimensions.*

**snippet of getView() method**

```
 if (position % 2 == 0) 
     holder.l1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cellbg);
     // l1 is reference of LinearLayout used in below xml.
 else 
     holder.l1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cellbg1);
```

**list structure(xml)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/FirstText"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:textSize="9sp"/>
    
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/SecondText"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/FirstText"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/FirstText"
        android:textSize="9sp"/>
    
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ThirdText"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/FirstText"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/FirstText"
        android:textSize="9sp"/>
    
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/FourthText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/FirstText"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/FirstText"/>
    
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivarrow"
        android:layout_width="15dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/FirstText"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/FirstText"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:gravity="top"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

*What am I doing wrong?*

[image: screen]

Comment: Parameters like `layout_alignTop` aren't working on a `LinearLayout`. Your Layout should work better when you use `RelativeLayout`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gravity:center_vertical?
I prefer make the TextView SingleLine.. I will seems a better look I think
and layout_alignTop layout_alignBottom only work in RelativeLayout
thx :)